# Can a nested class have a member pointer to the outer class?

Tags: c++

In C++, given a nested class, can inner class have a member pointer to the outer class?

```
class Outer{
public:
    class Inner{
    public:
        int i;
        Outer *ptr;

        Inner(){
            i =0;
            ptr = NULL;
            ....
        }
        ...

    };
}
```

If it is OK, are there anything/tricky issues that should be careful and cautious?

Comment: if you are shooting for 'it just works' then it should be fine. If you want to do the right way, then do consider single responsibility, DI principles

Comment: It's just a regular class. The only "tricky" thing is remembering that outside of `Outer`, its name is `Outer::Inner`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a pointer or reference to the outer class since it doesn't require a complete type. Declaring an object would instead require the type to be complete. See reference on [incomplete types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type)

This is the same reason why you can have a pointer to the same class as a data member:

```
class Outer
{
  Outer* p; // Outer is an incomplete type at this point
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is ok, there is no problem.
One thing I can think of that might surprise you is that in C++, inner classes do not have an implicit reference to an instance of the outer class. I don't think, however, it will be a problem to you since you are working with a pointer.